# HTML Rails View Format Question

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

How would I produce something like this in Rails ERB?

```
<li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio <span>Our work</span></a>
```

My problem is that ruby won't allow me to span inside of the link.

```
<%= link_to 'portfolio', portfolio_path %>
```

Anyway to get the Our Works Span inside of that link?

Thanks in Advance.

Solved

```
<% link_to portfolio_path do %> Portfolio <span>Our work</span> <% end %>
```

Comment: Solved my problem <% link_to portfolio_path do %>
Portfolio <span>Our work</span>
<% end %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the HTML string right in there like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Portfolio <span>Our work</span>', portfolio_path %>
```

Or, you can pass a block to enclose the link:

```
<% link_to portfolio_path do %>
Portfolio <span>Our work</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The first method doesn't quite work. But the second method exactly did the job. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Porfolio <span>Our Work</span>', portfolio_path %>
```